# How to get an exception from a task when the task generates events

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following scenario. A [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) that generates events and might throw an exception:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
new Task(() =>
    {
        while (condition)
        {
            // Generate standard .NET event.
            MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());

            // Maybe throw exception.
            if (somethingIsWrong) throw new Exception();
        }
    });
```

All pretty straightforward. I listen to the events using `Observable.FromEvent`:

```
var events =
    Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(h => myClass.MyEvent += h,
                                    h => myClass.MyEvent -= h);
events.Subscribe(
    ev => DoSomethingOnNext(ev),
    ex => DoSomethingOnError(ex),
    () => DoSomethingOnCompleted());
```

This all works fine when no exception occurs. When an exception is thrown by the task, however, I'd like to know this in my observable. The exception is now 'hidden' inside the task.

Can I only do this by creating another event when the exception takes place, wrapping it inside an [`IObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) and subscribing to this new observable? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Well, your observable, being created from the event, has no knowledge at all of the Task, let alone the exception that may be thrown.  You'll have to fire another event if there's an exception or totally rethink the design.  I'd like to come up with a suggestion ... maybe I'll come up with something ... in the meantime, perhaps think about Tasks in general and the way exceptions thrown in them are handled, first, then expand that to the Rx world.  Wish I could be more help at the moment.

Comment: I tried creating an Observable from TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, but I'm not able to get that to work ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
class Program
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new Program();            

        var task = new Task(() =>
        {
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                // Generate standard .NET event. 
                myClass.MyEvent(myClass, new EventArgs());
            }

            throw new Exception();
        });

        var obsTask = task.ToObservable();

        var events = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(h => myClass.MyEvent += h, h => myClass.MyEvent -= h);            

        events.TakeUntil(obsTask).Subscribe(
            ev => DoSomethingOnNext(ev), 
            ex => DoSomethingOnError(ex),
            () => DoSomethingOnCompleted());

        task.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void DoSomethingOnCompleted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingOnCompleted");
    }

    private static void DoSomethingOnError(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingOnError:" + ex.ToString());
    }

    private static void DoSomethingOnNext(IEvent<EventArgs> ev)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingOnNext:" + ev.ToString());
    }
```

The output is:

DoSomethingOnNext:System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.EventArgs]
DoSomethingOnNext:System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.EventArgs]
DoSomethingOnNext:System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.EventArgs]
DoSomethingOnNext:System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.EventArgs]
DoSomethingOnNext:System.Collections.Generic.Event`1[System.EventArgs]
DoSomethingOnError:System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at RxDisposeTests.Program.<>c_*DisplayClass9.b*_0() in C:\Users\Richard.Hein\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RxConsole\RxDisposeTests\Program.cs:line 25
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at RxDisposeTests.Program.<>c_*DisplayClass9.b*_0() in C:\Users\Richard.Hein\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RxConsole\RxDisposeTests\Program.cs:line 25
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---

**EDIT:**

Not sure if TakeUntil is a good solution, because Task might return something other than Exceptions, right?  So this could work:

```
var events = Observable.CreateWithDisposable<IEvent<EventArgs>>(observer =>
{
    var eventObs = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(
        h => myClass.MyEvent += h, h => myClass.MyEvent -= h);
    task.ToObservable().Subscribe(_ => { }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);
    return eventObs.Subscribe(observer.OnNext, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);
});

events.Subscribe(
    ev => DoSomethingOnNext(ev), 
    ex => DoSomethingOnError(ex),
    () => DoSomethingOnCompleted());
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. I didn't know about `Task.ToObservable`. I'll try it out.

Comment: You can use `TakeUntil` if you convert the task to: `task.ToObservable().Materialize().Where(n => n.Kind == NotificationKind.Error)`, which converts errors to a value.